# Integrating $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin (ax)}{x^3}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, complex-integration, trigonometric-integrals

I am trying to integrate this integral,

$$I_3 = \frac{ -4 }{ \pi} \int_0 ^{\infty} \frac{d\lambda}{\lambda^4} \cdot \sin(p_1 \lambda)\cdot \sin(p_2 \lambda) \left(-p_3 \lambda\cos\left(p_3 \lambda\right)\right)\cdot\sin\left(p_4 \lambda\right) \\
    = \frac{4p_3 }{ \pi} \int_0 ^{\infty} \frac{d\lambda}{\lambda^3} \cdot \sin(p_1 \lambda)\cdot \sin(p_2 \lambda) \cos\left(p_3 \lambda\right)\sin\left(p_4 \lambda\right)$$
I changed this trigonometric product to a sum of  $\sin\left(\left(dp_4+cp_3+bp_2+ap_1\right)\lambda\right)$ where $a,b,c,d= \pm1$ But then integral takes the form $\int_0 ^{\infty} \frac{d\lambda}{\lambda^4} \sin\left(k\lambda\right)$ Which seems divergent to me. Is there any other way to integrate this?

**Background:** I am trying to calculate $$ D_2(p_3,p_4) =\frac{-4}{\pi} \int \frac{d\lambda}{\lambda^4} \cdot \sin(p_1 \lambda)\cdot \sin(p_2 \lambda)
 \left(\sin\left(p_3 \lambda\right)-p_3 \lambda\cos\left((p_3 \lambda\right)\right)\cdot\left(\sin\left(p_4 \lambda\right)-p_4 \lambda\cos\left((p_4 \lambda\right)\right)$$ which has a finite value according to Appendix C of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.01629.pdf) and $I_3$ is one of the four terms after expanding it. If you can suggest any other simpler way to calculate $D_2$, that would also be great.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Yes each piece is divergent, but the full thing is finite. This is the same as $\int \frac{e^x-1}{x}dx$ being finite while both of $\int\frac{e^x}{x}dx$ and $\int \frac{dx}{x}$ is divergent. What they seem to do is to regularize these integrals by doing the integration over $\lambda \in [\epsilon,\infty)$ and then taking $\epsilon \to 0$ in the end.

Comment: Your integral $I_3$ converges - integrand does not have singularity at x=0 ($sinx\sim{x}$); it also can be evaluated by means of Parseval equality (we can use the Fourier Transform - integrand is even) and is the polynomial of third degree (consisting of p1...p4). $D_2$ can be expressed via the derivative of  $I_3$. Calculations are long but straightforward.

Comment: In the paper the integral is evaluated via Gamma function: first, you express all sin and cos via $\exp(ia\lambda)$ and then integrate each of integrals over $\lambda$, making a turn in the complex plane and expressing integrand via $\frac{\exp(-a\lambda)}{\lambda^4}$. These integrals become Gamma function of negative negative integer and formally diverges, but you can locate divergencies (by means small $\epsilon$) - in the final expression they cancel each other (because the initial integral converges).

Comment: $\displaystyle{\sin\left(ax\right) \over ax} = {1 \over 2}\int_{-1}^{1}\exp\left(\ic kax\right)\,{\rm d}k$ can be useful but it's a long evaluation. The integration along $\displaystyle\left(-\infty, \infty\right)$ will introduce a Dirac Delta. The remaining triple integral over $\displaystyle\left(-1,1\right)^{3}$ is a cumbersome one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int\frac{\sin (ax)}{x^4}dx=a^3 \int\frac{\sin (t)}{t^4}dt$$ Now, you need a few integrations by parts to get
$$\int\frac{\sin (t)}{t^4}dt=-\frac{\cos (t)}{6 t^2}+\frac{\left(t^2-2\right) \sin (t)}{6 t^3}-\frac{\text{Ci}(t)}{6}$$
$$I(\epsilon)=\int_\epsilon^\infty\frac{\sin (t)}{t^4}dt=\frac{\cos (\epsilon)}{6 \epsilon^2}-\frac{\left(\epsilon^2-2\right) \sin (\epsilon)}{6 \epsilon^3}+\frac{\text{Ci}(\epsilon)}{6}$$
$$I(\epsilon)=\frac{1}{2 \epsilon ^2}+\frac{1}{36} (6 \log (\epsilon )+6 \gamma -11)-\frac{\epsilon
   ^2}{240}+\frac{\epsilon ^4}{20160}+O\left(\epsilon ^6\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$I(a)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(ax)}{x^4}dx$$
we can analyse its converge by the following: $u=ax\Rightarrow x=u/a,\,dx=du/a$
$$I(a)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(u)}{(u/a)^4}\frac{du}a=a^3\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(u)}{u^4}du$$
now we need to look at what happens as the integrand tends to zero, to do this I will split it into two parts:
$$J=\int_0^\epsilon\frac{\sin(u)}{u^4}du+\int_\epsilon^\infty\frac{\sin(u)}{u^4}du$$
the problem is this first integral, for a small enough $\epsilon$ it is fair for us to say $\sin u\approx u$ so:
$$\int_0^\epsilon\frac{\sin u}{u^4}du=\int_0^\epsilon\frac1{u^3}du\to\infty$$